Не грузится CSS в Thymeleaf и Spring Boot
Всем привет.
Не грузится CSS файл. Как я понял все дело в мапингах. К примеру у меня такой маппинг:
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/event")
    public class EventController {
    
        @GetMapping()
        public String create() {
            return "event/ajouter";
        }
     }

Он работает превосходно и все загружает. Но если я изменю путь в @RequestMapping:
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/event/add")
    public class EventController {
    
        @GetMapping()
        public String create() {
            return "event/ajouter";
        }
     }

или в @GetMapping:
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/event")
    public class EventController {
    
        @GetMapping("/add")
        public String create() {
            return "event/ajouter";
        }
     }

то CSS не грузится.
CSS фалы находятся в папке static, там все отлично. В Spring Security настроено .anyRequest().permitAll().

Все оказалось очень просто. Я забыл добавить / перед css в пути до css файла.
Вот так все работает идеально:
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">

